# Boost: Function Output Iterator, reinventing the wheel

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Normally someone would just go and grab Boost's [Function Output Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) but I'm not allowed to use Boost at work.  That said, I just want to use the `copy` function to traverse a collection, call a function on each item, take the output of that function, and finally `push_back` it onto another collection.  I've written some code:

```
#include <iterator>
using std::iterator;
using std::output_iterator_tag;

template<typename Container, typename Function>
struct Back_Transform_Iterator : public iterator<output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void>{
    explicit Back_Transform_Iterator(Container &_container, const Function &_function) 
        : m_Container(_container),
        m_Function(_function){}

    Back_Transform_Iterator<Container,Function>& operator= (const typename Function::argument_type &value){ 
      m_Container.push_back( m_Function( value ) );

      return *this; 
    }

    Back_Transform_Iterator<Container,Function>& operator* (){ return *this; }
    Back_Transform_Iterator<Container,Function>& operator++ (){ return *this; }
    Back_Transform_Iterator<Container,Function> operator++ (int){ return *this; }

    typedef Container container_type;

private:
    Container   &m_Container;
    Function    m_Function;
};

template<typename C, typename F>
Back_Transform_Iterator<C,F> back_transform_inserter(C &_container, F &_unary_function){
    return Back_Transform_Iterator<C,F>( _container, _unary_function );
}
```

but... I'm getting compilation problems.  Fairly certain it's to do with the `operator*()` call.  I have no idea how to effectively dereference the container's objects so that they object the function's effects.  Error:

```
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Back_Transform_Iterator<Container,Function>'
```

the items I'm iterating over are not mutable.  Anyone know how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Any reason you don't use `std::transform` and `back_inserter`?

Comment: Gah!  Put it as an answer and let me give you credit for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `transform` instead:

```
transform(src.begin(), src.end(), back_inserter(container), func);
```

---

Note that `const` applied on a reference type is a no-op. So if `argument_type` is `T&`, then saying `const argument_type` does not yield back `const T&` but `T&` again. So if your source items are constant you would try to bind them to the non-const reference parameter of `operator=` in case that `argument_type` is a reference:

```
typedef int &intr;
const intr& a = 0; // fails - "const" is ignored!
```

Comment: Reached my daily limit of upvotes, will have to come back later to give you a +1.